# How can I use FCM to send links to an android app

Tags: android, firebase, android-activity, firebase-cloud-messaging

Upon clicking the notification, I want it to open the link in a separate browser. It doesn't matter if it launches the app or not. The final thing should be opening in a browser.

A detailed guide of code and procedures would be really helpful.

Any alternative idea would also be helpful.

## AskFirebase

Comment: so what is the issue there, make an intent to open the link in browsser, so when ever the user clicks it will open the link in browser

Comment: FCM does not allow sending of links as such. How can I do so?

Comment: As when you gets fcm message, there is a service class which handles all things. Right ?

Comment: Yes. Please expand on that

Comment: So there you can add the link to intent

Comment: and you can pass string in payload in fcm so there should be no issue in sending links

Comment: It would be great if you could demonstrate with code or screenshots or examples. I am a pure novice. Some help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass links or text directly from firebase console when app is in background . You need to use Advanced Rest Client which is available in Chrome extensions.

Here is an example what code you need to write in Advanced Rest Client

```
 { "data": {
"message": "Yee",
"image"  : "url.jpg",
"sound": "default",
"linkk": "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57335468/how-can-i-use-fcm-to-send-links-to-an-android-app"
   },
    "to" : "/topics/test"
}
```

In this example those who subscribed to topic test will receive this message and will be able to open link in your app.

But!!!!
You should try when your app is in foreground the link will work fine even when you send notification from firebase console.

Comment: Please expand a bit on that. It would be great.

Comment: @AnuragMittal just download ADVANCED REST CLIENT in google chrome extension and follow this tutorial   https://medium.com/@selvaganesh93/firebase-cloud-messaging-important-rest-apis-be79260022b5  .  Hope it may help you :)